# How to SELECT from a many to many linking-table with three Foreign Keys ??? Pic in desc

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Hey guys I would like to learn how to query from many to many database. This is a example of Database with three tables and one **many to many table with three Foreign Keys**. **How would you perform SELECT statement on `st_glowne_others` table?**

For example if I would like to SELECT all posible results from 'st_components' table, 
which links with specific value from name column from 'st_glowne' table, 
and specyfic value from name column from 'st_pages' table. 
Thanks in advance!.

[image: many to many with three foreign key]

TABLE1

```
CREATE TABLE `st_glowne` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
 `location` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT './',
 PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
 KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci
```

TABLE2

```
CREATE TABLE `st_pages` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
 `filelocation` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pages/',
 PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
 KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_c
```

TABLE3

```
CREATE TABLE `st_components` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
 `location` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'components/',
 PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
 KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci
```

This is the Table we want to query from:

```
CREATE TABLE `st_glowne_others` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `st_glowne` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
 `st_pages` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
 `st_components` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `st_glowne` (`st_glowne`),
 KEY `st_pages` (`st_pages`),
 KEY `st_components` (`st_components`),
 KEY `st_components_2` (`st_components`),
 CONSTRAINT `st_glowne_others_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`st_components`) REFERENCES `st_components` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `st_glowne_others_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`st_glowne`) REFERENCES `st_glowne` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `st_glowne_others_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`st_pages`) REFERENCES `st_pages` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci
```

Could you please show me how to query from it ? MANY MANY THANKS !

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is with a join:

```
SELECT * FROM `st_glowne_others` go
LEFT JOIN `st_glowne` ON `st_glowne`.name = go.st_glowne
LEFT JOIN `st_pages` ON `st_pages`.name = go.st_pages
LEFT JOIN `st_components` ON `st_components`.name = go.st_components
```

However, I'd recommend re thinking your schema - is there any reason for the PK to be the name field? You have an `AUTO INCREMENT` id column which is a much more standard way to join two tables.

eg (for each of the tables):

```
CREATE TABLE `st_glowne` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
 `location` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT './',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

Then with your `st_glowne_others` table, referencing the ID columns.

```
CREATE TABLE `st_glowne_others` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `st_glowne_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `st_glowne_id` (`st_glowne_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `st_glowne_others_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`st_glowne_id`) REFERENCES `st_glowne` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
)
```